# How do I pass a dynamic variable name created using enquo() to dplyr's mutate for evaluation?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

I'm creating a workflow that contains the same piping steps of renaming, selecting by, then mutating all using a name I provide prior to the pipe.

I have had success using `enquo()` and `!!`(bang bang) to rename to my desired string and then select it again, but when I reach the mutate step it either repeats the text string as the column values or will not evaluate.

I've recreated the code below:

```
#Testing rename, select, and mutate use cases for enquo()

#Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(magrittr)

#Create name I want to pass
new_var <- quo("new_name")

#Create Test Data
t1 <- tibble(Year = c(2000:2004),
             old_name = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, NA))
```

I can rename the column with `quo_name()` and `:=`

```
t1 %>% 
  rename( !! quo_name(new_var) := old_name)
```

I can select on it using `!!`

```
t1 %>% 
  rename( !! quo_name(new_var) := old_name) %>% 
  select(Year, !!new_var)
```

But I can't then call that column in mutate and use the values

```
t1 %>% 
  rename( !! quo_name(new_var) := old_name) %>% 
  select(Year, !!new_var) %>% 
  mutate(test_var = (!! new_var))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'new_var' object is a `quosure` on a string.  Extract the string, convert it to symbol and then do the evaluation

```
t1 %>% 
   rename( !! quo_name(new_var) := old_name) %>% 
   select(Year, !!new_var) %>% 
   mutate(testvar = !! rlang::sym(rlang::quo_name(new_var)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   Year new_name testvar
#  <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1  2000       NA      NA
#2  2001        1       1
#3  2002        1       1
#4  2003        1       1
#5  2004       NA      NA
```

---

Also, if we start with unquoted the `new_var` in `quosure`, then the OP's code works

```
new_var = quo(new_name)
t1 %>% 
     rename(!! new_var := old_name) %>% 
     select(Year, !!new_var) %>% 
     mutate(testvar = !! new_var)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   Year new_name testvar
#  <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1  2000       NA      NA
#2  2001        1       1
#3  2002        1       1
#4  2003        1       1
#5  2004       NA      NA
```

Comment: This also works,  and maintains my original `new_var <- enquo("new_name")`

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the first line with:

```
new_var <- sym("new_name")
```

In this case your existing code should run, but you could also simplify it, e.g.:

```
t1 %>% 
  rename( !! new_var := old_name) %>% 
  select(Year, !! new_var) %>% 
  mutate(test_var = (!! new_var))
```

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it was helpful.